# How to efficiently rename my URL's?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Lets say I'm creating a website about with 4 pages about bananas, apples, tomatoes and carrots, so I currently have 4 `.html` files: `bananas.php`, `apples.php` etc.

I suppose I would like to have `bananas.php` show as:

`domain.com/fruits/bananas-are-good/` (as I see many websites do it that way),

and `carrots.php` to show as `domain.com/vegetables/carrots-info/` and so on.

meaning I want to:

1. have a categorizing subfolder
2. not have any `.php` in the url
3. have a custom, longer name for each page.

What are my options and what is most recommended to achieve this?

I know I can manually create a folder in my domain's root folder named "fruits", 
and then create a folder named "bananas-are-good",
and then upload bananas.php as index.php.

But I don't think this is what pro webmasters really do.

I suppose you might tell me there's an option to create an .htaccess rule that changes each ".php" in the url to a "/", but then I would still have to rename my `bananas.php` file to `bananas-are-good.php` on my computer/root folder, and I would still have to create the "Fruits" folder, which is not comfortable **in case I want to update all the .php files on my website at once via  ftp** (as I would have to manually go to each subfolder, and upload the relevant files, instead of uploading everything at once) - what if I would have 20 folders? it would be exhausting and inefficient.

**I would also need to link the pages to each other, and I'm not sure how should they be linked?** would I have to use absolute url's? (like change the link in my `apples.php` from the current `<a href = "bananas.php">` to `<a href = "http://domain.com/fruits/bananas-are-good/">` (this applies for the META tag `rel=canonical` as well).

I would also want to reserve the option to have visitors arriving to links like `mydomain.com/vegetables/carrots-info/?referrer=name` (In case that matters anything).

So what is the best all round solution? I'm hoping there's an easy, free, and quick solution that does not require complicated tech skills (nor install anything), and that would allow my to keep using FTP for updating the website, and not some sort of a web interface.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just edit your `.htaccess` file and add the necessary lines in the following fashion:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fruits/bananas_are_good/?$ banana.php [L]
RewriteRule ^vegetables/carrots-info/?$ carrots.php [L]
```

Comment: NC means case insensitive match and R means a redirect. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html